# software update aplication not work

Tags: updates

after a failed update system, I restarted my computer and all be ok but I can't launch the software update aplication, it's working, but I can't see the status of updates or any information.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating your machine through synaptic. if it updates / upgrades through synaptic, restart the computer and your update application will start working again.

regards